# BitmapData cut-off

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata, rasterizing

I am writing a MovieClip rasterizer which rasterizes all the frames in the specified movieclip. Here's the code for rasterizing:

`for ( var i:int = start; i <= end; i++ )
{
 //goto the next frame
 clip.gotoAndStop( i );`

//get the bounds
 bounds = clip.getBounds(clip);

//create a new bitmapdata container
 bitmapData = new BitmapData(
  transformer.width == -1 ? bounds.width : transformer.width,
  transformer.height == -1 ? bounds.height : transformer.height,
  transformer.transparent,
  transformer.color
 );

if (transformer.matrix.tx == 0 && transformer.matrix.ty == 0) transformer.translateToZero( bounds );

//draw the bitmap data with the transformers
 bitmapData.draw(
  this._source,
  transformer.matrix,
  transformer.colorTransform,
  transformer.blendMode,
  transformer.clipRect, //new Rectangle(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.height),
  transformer.smoothing
 );

//push the data on the array
 frames.push( bitmapData );
}

Now the result is different - http://i42.tinypic.com/lfv52.jpg - the black one is the rasterized version ( i used a color transform on it to test it :P). Note the head and left shoe. Anyone knows what the problem is? I've seen people adding 'extra' pixels to their boundary box at the BitmapData constructor, but thats the right solution.

Anyone got an idea how to fit in the character nicely?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what *transformer.translateToZero()* does but, are you sure the character is always aligned at (0, 0)?

I mean, you should pass *bounds* as *BitmapData.draw()'s clipRect* argument if you wanted it to copy the whole *MovieClip*.

Comment: translateToZero does this: _matrix.translate( -bounds.x, -bounds.y ); //_matrix = flash.geom.Matrix

It inverses the current x and y axis of the movieclip to zero. If i pass the bounds to the clipRect of the BitmapData.draw method 1/4 of the movieclip is drawn since the the movieclip is centered.